# What are the side effects of using while-loops in javascript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

These two javascript while-loops are absolutely identical.
But, once we remove 'console.log('end')'
after one of them, it will spit out extra '41' number in Chrome console and in Node.js v14.8.0. Is it what is called 'a side effect'?

```js
// While-loop 1
const max = 40, min = 30;
let i = min + 1;
while (i < max) {
  console.log(i);
  i += 2;
}
console.log('end');
// 31 33 35 37 39
```

```js
// While-loop 2
const max = 40, min = 30;
let i = min + 1;
while (i < max) {
  console.log(i);
  i += 2;
}
// 31 33 35 37 39 41
```

Comment: I don't see a difference when running these.

Comment: I can verify that there is an extra "41" printed *if the latter code is run in the console*. This might be a bug.

Comment: I run these two while-loops in Chrome dev tool and there is a difference.

Comment: The extra "41" is also printed if the code is run in a node console (tested in v14.8.0).

Comment: That's the return value of the assignment. `console.log` would return `undefined`

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, but why is it printed? It's a little confusing.

Comment: @kol because in a REPL environment, you always get the last returned value printed.

Comment: @VLAZ I know that, and it's OK if you type a simple assignment and hit Enter, but I find this behavior strange when I type in a more complex expression, like a loop with multiple assignments... (that was my case few days ago). I also don't remember Chrome REPL behaving this way in the past *in case of more complex expressions*.

Comment: Hmm... I was wrong. I tested this phenomenon in Chromium 69 and it also printed the extra "41".

Comment: @kol you'd still get the *last* value. That's always been the case. At most, you might get `undefined` if the last thing was a statement only code like `let x = 42` - then you'd get `undefined` because there is no return value.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the clarification. I think you should write an answer!

Comment: @kol and VLAZ, I agree. Thank you!